# Inequality on infinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inequality, infinite-matrices

Take the square of sum of elements in every column for first finite rows (say m). Then take their sum for all the columns (say n). If $m,n \rightarrow \infty$, can we show that it is bounded by some constant times the sum of squares of all the elements of the infinite matrix.

Comment: @DavidRaveh The terms are positive.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you're asking whether every infinite matrix $A$ satisfies
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\Big(\sum_{j=1}^mA_{jk}\Big)^2\leq C\sum_{j,k=1}^\infty |A_{jk}|^2
$$
for some constant $C$ and all $m,n\in\mathbb N$. This, however, is not true.
Take
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0&\cdots\\
\frac12&0&0&0&\cdots\\
\frac13&0&0&0&\cdots\\
\frac14&0&0&0&\cdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}\,;
$$
then
$
\sum_{k=1}^n(\sum_{j=1}^mA_{jk})^2=(\sum_{j=1}^m\frac1j)^2
$, whereas
$
\sum_{j,k=1}^\infty |A_{jk}|^2=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac1{j^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6
$.
As $\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^m\frac1j=\infty$, there for all constants $C$ exists $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^m\frac1j>\pi\sqrt{\frac{C}6}$.
Therefore
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^n\Big(\sum_{j=1}^mA_{jk}\Big)^2= \Big(\sum_{j=1}^m\frac1j\Big)^2 >\frac{C\pi^2}6  =C\sum_{j,k=1}^\infty |A_{jk}|^2 \,,
$$
which is the desired contradiction.